# Ссылки и яндекс

Tags: php, ссылки

Есть страница bmw.php (список машин марки бмв). Хочу переименовать файл на mashina_bmw.php (список машин марки бмв)

Что делать? Просто добавить второй файл и все, а первый не удалять? Что яндекс подумает?

Есть страница opel.php, где есть список машин опель. И есть страница cars/opel.php, где тоже есть тот же список машин опель, но чуть-чуть по-другому расположен. Могу оставить или дать разные названия файлам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^bmw.php$ /mashina_bmw.php [R=301,L]
```

Ничего страшного не произойдет.

Про тире и подчеркивание: Яндексу есть разница в словах, т.е. если слова разделены как тире (-), то он поймет как 2 слова, если подчеркивание (_), то поймет как одно слово. Это важно если в названии страницы есть ключевые поисковые слова.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте со старых страниц 301 php редирект на новый, в url страниц не используйте "_", а заменяйте этот символ "-", т.к. тогда пользователям будет удобней набирать адрес сайта и позиции поэтому в ПС будут выше.

Comment: Откуда дровишки про различия ранжирования у адресов с «_» и «-» у поисковых систем? Звучит, честно говоря, как СЕОшная байка, мало имеющая отношения к действительности.

Comment: вы хоть знаете что за редирект Яндекс может по шапке дать и отчислить?

Comment: За корректный 301? Ну-ну.

Воистину мир SEOшных сказок безграничен.

Comment: Вы почитайте справку веб-мастеров Google, внимательно почитайте, там говорится, что _ не желательно использоват в адресе страниц, лучше использовать -, т.к. так пользователям удобней. За 301 редирект ничего не будет. И вообще, советую ориентироваться на Google - более перспективная в количестве трафика ПС (в будущем, сейчас они рекламу своего браузера крутят на всех телеканалах, соответственно и постоянных пользователей у ПС становится больше, дефолтная поисковая система ведь Google в этом браузере).

Comment: Разницы между _ и - в адресах нет, кто хочет доказать обратне - предоставьте пруфлинк, как всегда сказочки на ночь ^^